# Voiculescu theorem for non-separable $C^*$-algebras

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

In many refernce books, when the authors mention the Voiculescu theorem. They often state that the $C^*$-algebras are separable. See [A proposition about Voiculescu's Theorem in C*-algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/712337/a-proposition-about-voiculescus-theorem-in-c-algebra?r=SearchResults)

If the $C^*$-algebras are non-separable, does the theorem also hold?

Comment: Links are OK to enhance a question but they should not be abused and, in particular, users should not be forced to follow a link just to find out the statement of the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Already [Glimm's Lemma](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2000895/22857) (of which Voiculescu's Theorem is a generalization) fails for (some) non-separable C$^*$-algebras.

For instance consider $B(H)$, with $H=\ell^2(\mathbb N)$ and let $A$ be the diagonal masa (that is, the copy of $\ell^\infty(\mathbb N)$ acting as diagonal operators). It is well-known that the pure states of $A$ that are zero on $A\cap K(H)$ are in correspondence with the non-principal ultrafilers on $\mathbb N$. And there are $2^c$ of these. On the other hand, the number of sequences in $H$ is $c$. So by cardinality there are pure states which cannot be limits of pointwise evaluations on a sequence.

Comment: Thanks, I have another question: If $A$ is separable, but the nondegenerate representation of $A$ is non-separable(eg,$\pi：A \rightarrow B(H)$, where $H$ is non-separable), does the Voiculescu's theorem also hold?

Comment: I'm not totally sure, but on a superficiail look it seems to me that the dimension of $H$ plays no role in the proof of Voiculescu's Theorem.

Comment: I found in many papers and reference books, when the authors state the Voiculescu's theorem, they srtess that the $C^*$-algebra is separable and the representation space is also separable.

Comment: Could be. I haven't tought about this stuff in years, and I have zero intution for unitary equivalent modulo the compacts.